# How to test a module bandwidth with ftp

Tags: c++, tcp, ftp, bandwidth

I was asked to test a module of c++ that I built with ftp.

This module consists of transmitting data (bits) from one computer to the other.

How can I use ftp in Windows, transmitting for example a file of 1Gbyte from one pc to the other using my module and ftp?

This is basically to see the bandwidth and calculate it with different options (ETHERNET and with VPN).